# rstudio is slow and a file downloads with red dots and a pink background

Tags: r

Whenever I open `Rstudio`, for one project the console shows only red dots with a pink background:

[Console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pdwm.png)

In other files the screen shot is fine but running code is painfully slow.

On the diagnostic file, for today's date when I ran the code, I get the following:

```
09 Nov 2018 03:36:36 [rsession-shill] ERROR jsonrpc error 5 (Invalid json or unexpected error occurred while parsing); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::getChunkJson(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\rmarkdown\NotebookChunkDefs.cpp:140; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::source::{anonymous}::writeDocToJson(rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio::session::source_database::SourceDocument>, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionSource.cpp:87
09 Nov 2018 03:45:46 [rsession-shill] ERROR jsonrpc error 5 (Invalid json or unexpected error occurred while parsing); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::getChunkJson(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\rmarkdown\NotebookChunkDefs.cpp:140; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::source::{anonymous}::writeDocToJson(rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio::session::source_database::SourceDocument>, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionSource.cpp:87
09 Nov 2018 14:53:21 [rsession-shill] ERROR jsonrpc error 5 (Invalid json or unexpected error occurred while parsing); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::getChunkJson(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\rmarkdown\NotebookChunkDefs.cpp:140; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::source::{anonymous}::writeDocToJson(rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio::session::source_database::SourceDocument>, rstudio::core::json::Object*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionSource.cpp:87
09 Nov 2018 15:13:51 [rsession-shill] WARNING Excluded unsafe source document (C:/SAM/DASHBOARDMARKDOWNMASTER3.Rmd): File is binary (has null byte sequence); LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::source_database::logUnsafeSourceDocument(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const string&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:678
```

I just installed the newest version of `Rstudio`.

Any ideas?

Comment: And the screen shot is as follows:

Comment: you should uninstall RStudio and reinstall it. If this continues you should post an issue on their GitHub or a thread in their community forum.